# How to get information back and forth between classes?

Tags: java, class, variables

Hello im learning how to handle multiple classes in one code but here is a problem i couldnt figure out how it is called nor an answer to it. So i have one variable x in Back class, i get it to the main then i want to push it back to the back class and then again pull it to the main. Its a simplified code so i can use it as an example to change variables in other classes depending on certain condintions. Currently its not working.

```
package Classes;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Back Q = new Back();
        double f = Q.x;
        System.out.println(Q.g);
    }
}
//-------------------
package Classes;
public class Back {
    Main K = new Main();
    double x = 10;
    double g= K.f; //f cannot be resolved or is not a field
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `K.f` to be? Does `Q.x` work? What is `Q.g`? I think a good start point can be learning the concept of `instance variables`, `static variables` and `local variables`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to read more about access modifiers in java. There are few main things that you must understand:

1. Difference between static and non-static members;
2. Difference between different access levels (public, protected, package-private/default and private);
3. Local variables.

These things can help you to decide what type of variables you need.

Right now you're trying to get an access from a static main method to a non-static package-private variable in a neighbor class via newly created object, and is ok.

But you also try to get an access from the inside of a non-static object to a local variable that is defined in a static method - this is impossible. Instead, it is probably better to introduce setter methods or introduce other methods that accept external parameters.

Answer (score -1):

The attribute x in class Back is package-private, so it can be accessed directly via the Back object called Q you create in main().

In the class Back you try to access the attribute f of the class Main which is references by the object called K. But the class Main does not define any attributes.

You only have a local variable called f in the scope of the main() method that has been definied in class Main.

A possible solution could be something like this. But I don't know what problem you want to solve with your code. So here is just an idea that should compile...

```
package Classes;
public class Main {

    double d = 5.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Back Q = new Back();
        double f = Q.x;
        System.out.println(Q.g);
    }
}
//-------------------
package Classes;
public class Back {
    Main K = new Main();
    double x = 10;
    double g = K.d;
}
```

Comment: And how do i fix that?

Comment: I've added a suggestion that should compile. Don't know if it's what you want to achieve.

Comment: Default visibility for a class member is package-private, not public. Also, your code does a very different thing if compared to an example from the original question.